# Test and evaluate my answers classifier?

Tags: app, chrome-extensions, stackoverflow

I have created a web applicability that analyses the answers to a question and ranks them by usefulness. This is part of my thesis, and I need to get some real developers feed back.

Here is a link to the app in the chrome store [Stack Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverride/deckmfefillmikcadfmapaokkhbfdblh)

All I need is for a few people to rate the rankings.

[image: rate]

like this

[image: thank you]

Thank you to anyone who takes part